# C++ OOP not storing and displaying content correctly

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to create a program that takes input from the user about the length, width, and height of a box, and sends it to the appropriate member function and returns it back to the main. My length, width, and height are not storing and displaying themselves correctly in my OOP using Visual Studio. The code seems to take my last input (which is height) and set it to Length, and set the rest to 1.0. I can't figure out what im doing wrong here.

My GiftWrap.h file

```
#ifndef GIFTWRAP_H
#define GIFTWRAP_H
using namespace std;

class GiftWrap{
private:
    double length;
    double width;
    double height;
    double taxRate;
    double pricePerInch;
    double subTotal;
    double total;
    double tax;

public:
    GiftWrap();
    GiftWrap(double, double);
    bool setLength(double);
    bool setWidth(double);
    bool setHeight(double);
    bool setTaxRate(double);
    bool setPricePerInch(double);
    double getLength() const;
    double getWidth() const;
    double getHeight() const;
    double getPriceperInch() const;
    double getTaxRate() const;
    double calcSubTotal();
    double calcTax();
    double calcTotal();
};

#endif
```

My GiftWrap.cpp file:

```
#include "GiftWrap.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

GiftWrap::GiftWrap(){
    length = 1.0;
    height = 1.0;
    width = 1.0;
    pricePerInch = 0.0036;
    taxRate = 0.08;
}

GiftWrap::GiftWrap(double r, double c){
    length = 1.0;
    height = 1.0;
    width = 1.0;
    setPricePerInch(r);
    setTaxRate(c);
}


double GiftWrap::getHeight() const{
    return height;
}

double GiftWrap::getWidth() const{
    return width;
}

double GiftWrap::getLength() const{
    return length;
}
double GiftWrap::getPriceperInch() const{
    return pricePerInch;
}

double GiftWrap::getTaxRate() const{
    return taxRate;
}

double GiftWrap::calcSubTotal(){

    subTotal = pricePerInch * ((2 * length * width) + (2 * length * height) + (2 * width * height));
    return subTotal;
}

double GiftWrap::calcTax() {
    tax = subTotal * taxRate;
    return tax;
}

double GiftWrap::calcTotal() {
    total = tax + subTotal;
    return total;
}

bool GiftWrap::setHeight(double h){
    if (h > 0){
        height = h;
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

bool GiftWrap::setWidth(double w){
    if (w > 0){
        width = w;
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}

bool GiftWrap::setLength(double l){
    if (l > 0){
        length = l;
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}
bool GiftWrap::setTaxRate(double t){
    if (t > 0 && t < 1){
        taxRate = t;
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}

bool GiftWrap::setPricePerInch(double p){
    if (p > 0){
        pricePerInch = p;
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

My GiftWrapApp.cpp file:

```
#include "GiftWrap.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void showInvoice(GiftWrap&);

int main(){
    char selection;
    double len;
    double wid;
    double hei;
    string storeName = "Sallys Gifts";
    GiftWrap sallys(0.0025, 0.925);
    do{
        cout << "GIFT WRAP INVOICE GENERATOR" << endl
            << "------------------------------" << endl
            << "a)Generate Gift Wrap Invoice" << endl
            << "q)Quit" << endl;
        cin >> selection;
        if (selection == 'a' || selection == 'A'){
            cout << "Please enter the length of your box:" << endl;
            cin >> len;
            while (!sallys.setLength(len)){
                cout << "Invalid Selection, try again" << endl;
                cin >> len;
            }
            cout << "Please enter the width of your box:" << endl;
            cin >> wid;
            while (!sallys.setLength(wid)){
                cout << "Invalid Selection, try again" << endl;
                cin >> wid;
            }
            cout << "Please enter the height of your box:" << endl;
            cin >> hei;
            while (!sallys.setLength(hei)){
                cout << "Invalid Selection, try again" << endl;
                cin >> hei;
            }
            cout << "\nGIFT WRAP INVOICE - " << storeName << endl
                << "----------------------------------" << endl;
            showInvoice(sallys);
        }
        else if (selection == 'q' || selection == 'Q'){
            cout << "Thank you for using this program!" << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "Invalid Selection, try again" << endl;
        }

    } while (selection != 'q' && selection != 'Q');
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void showInvoice(GiftWrap& r){
    cout << "Box Length: " << fixed << setprecision(2)  << r.getLength() << endl;
    cout << "Box width: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << r.getWidth() << endl;
    cout << "Box Height: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << r.getHeight() << endl;
    cout << "Price Per Inch: " << fixed << setprecision(4) << r.getPriceperInch() << "\n" << endl;

    cout << "Subtotal: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << r.calcSubTotal() << endl;
    cout << "Tax: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << r.calcTax() << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << "----------" << endl;
    cout << "TOTAL: " <<  fixed << setprecision(2) << r.calcTotal() << endl;
    cout << endl;

}
```

here is the result that im getting:
http://s10.postimg.org/q97jhgc4p/11111.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have a look at the page on [Minimal Complete Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This code is much too long and complicated; if you had reduced it to a simpler example, you would probably have spotted the mistake yourself, and failing that you would have made our task much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `GiftWrapApp.cpp` inside the `do while()` loop, there a two mistakes:

```
cout << "Please enter the width of your box:" << endl;
cin >> wid;
while (!sallys.setLength(wid)){ // <----- Should be sallys.setWidthd()!!!
    cout << "Invalid Selection, try again" << endl;
    cin >> wid;
}
cout << "Please enter the height of your box:" << endl;
cin >> hei;
while (!sallys.setLength(hei)){ // <-- Should be sallys.setHight(hei)!! 
    cout << "Invalid Selection, try again" << endl;
    cin >> hei;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: My god i need to get some coffee into me. I could have sworn I check my code like over 10 times in main, and gave up (thinking it would be in my constructor). Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was trying to do that earlier, but it said you had to wait 2 minutes -_-. Thanks for your quick response.